# Letters appear one character to the left/right of where I expect it to

Tags: overleaf, sharelatex

On (at least my) sharelatex there must be some kind of setting which makes the letters appear one character behind or in front of where I expect it to.  I don't know how to explain it - hopefully you get what I mean.  If I press delete, it deletes the character one to the left (or right?) instead, and if I type a letter it keeps appearing once space to the left or right of where it should.  I realise it must be some kind of feature which somehow can be useful but if I just want it as "normal" how can I tell it not to do this?

Comment: Sharelatex- and Overleaf-specific questions should be posted to the Overleaf helpdesk. I hear their LaTeX support team is top-notch.

Comment: It sounds like you have inserted a invisible bi-directional control character. Have you cut and pasted any text from a text using a right to left language such as Arabic or hebrew?

Comment: are you really still using a sharelatex account? I had assumed they had all been moved over to overleaf years ago?

Comment: oh no, i think you're right, it's overleaf.  

i've copied and pasted georgian text (but this is left to right...). hmm.

Comment: can you share a link to the text? (the smallest text you have that shows the issue)

Comment: i think i'm not explaining right maybe.  my problem won't be visible from the text, like it's lierally the moving bar in a text where you type the letters on your screen - the letters appear a few characters off where i expect them to be.